# Source for PKCS#11 Header Files

Tags: standards, pkcs11

Is there a known authoritative source for the ANSI C header files for PKCS#11 Cryptoki? Specifically, I am having trouble locating pkcs11.h, pkcs11t.h, and pkcs11f.h for v2.30 and v2.40. Are there known MD5 or SHA hashes for these files?

Comment: Don't see them either. If in doubt, kindly ask the authors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In May 2015, header files were uploaded to the OASIS PKCS 11 TC document repository by Dina Kurktchi-Nimeh that were versioned v2.40. However, they were uploaded to the "Working Drafts" folder. The meeting minutes from 2015-04-15 state that v2.40 is complete, but there is an action item for Dina to publish header files for v2.40 with errata (what would hopefully become v2.41). There is an action item for Chris (presumably Zimman?) to publish the final 2.40 (w/o errata) headers, but there are no uploads from him.

[Official PKCS #11 v2.40 Announcement](https://www.oasis-open.org/news/announcements/pkcs-11-cryptographic-token-interface-base-specification-interface-profiles-curre)

[pkcs11t.h](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/document.php?document_id=55657&wg_abbrev=pkcs11)

[pkcs11f.h](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/document.php?document_id=55656&wg_abbrev=pkcs11)

[pkcs11.h](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/document.php?document_id=55655&wg_abbrev=pkcs11)

[2015-04-15 Meeting Notes](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/55653/Minutes15042015-PKCS11.pdf)

Comment: It's been a while, but I'm interested in how exactly do you go from Oasis web site to the PKCS11 header files, without using Google. That site is a nightmare to navigate!

Comment: @KCWong It's changed even since the last time I looked at it. I needed to find the SAML 2.0 Bindings spec the other day and had to go digging. Used to know exactly where it was.

Answer (score 8):

The PKCS#11 standard has transitioned from RSA to the OASIS group:
https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=pkcs11

I am not sure why RSA/EMC's site doesn't mention this.

I believe that v2.30 was close to finalization, but was never formally released.  I am not sure what happened but v2.40 is now the current release candidate.

v2.20 is the current revision and header files are accessible by following the link that Mr. Stone provided.

CryptSoft (Tim Hudson is a PKCS#11 leader) has a very good resource page:
http://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the current 2.40 version is a release candidate, although I could not really understand the way versioning is realised or if the header files are going to be updated in any way. The OASIS website is IMHO insufficiently clear on this.

Answer (score 1):

These headers now appear on the oasis github: https://github.com/oasis-tcs/pkcs11/tree/master/published , which as of the time of writing includes the latest released files (3.01)

Answer (score 0):

The RSA page looks to be the place to go:

PKCS #11: Cryptographic Token Interface Standard
http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/pkcs-11-cryptographic-token-interface-standard.htm#

Although I don't see MD5 or SHA hashes.

Comment: Thanks, and I did see this page previously, the issue is it says the current version is v2.20. I understand v2.40 was recently finalized, but that doesn't explain what happened to v2.30.

Answer (score 0):

The OASIS PKCS 11 technical committee page can be found here: https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=pkcs11.

From that page, scrolling down to the "Technical Work Produced by the Committee" section, you find some concrete artefacts.

The official header files for v2.40, with errata, are found here: http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/errata01/os/include/pkcs11-v2.40/. There you will find the following files:

- pkcs11.h
- pkcs11f.h
- pkcs11t.h